# How would I fix the Syntax error I'm getting on my handleChange function?

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the following error in the console.

It's something wrong about the handler.

[image: the error message picture here]

I'm not sure what's going on, but here the entire component code.

```
import React from 'react';
import TextWidget from './TextWidget';

/*
 * Handles removing dashes from SSNs by keeping the user input in local state
 * and saving the transformed version instead
 */
export default class SSNWidget extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { val: props.value };
  }
  handleChange = val => {
    // If val is blank or undefined, pass undefined to onChange
    let strippedSSN;
    if (val) {
      strippedSSN = val.replace(/[- ]/g, '');
    }

    this.setState({ val }, () => {
      this.props.onChange(strippedSSN);
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <TextWidget
        {...this.props}
        value={this.state.val}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please put your code/error in your question, rather than linking to an image. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just posted it. Please let me know if I need to add more information. Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, it's also good form to copy/paste the full error as text into your question as well. Screenshots really aren't a preferred way of including text.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I'm going to update the question.

Comment: How about `handleChange(val) {` instead?

Comment: @Khalt That gave the same error message.

Comment: @DeAndreBoston are you sure? https://jsfiddle.net/kn1gdo82/ It runs just fine on the fiddle.

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say its something wrong with your babel config, not the function itself. You may need to include a plugin like [@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties)

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot it looks like something is wrong with your babel configuration. Follow the guide [here](https://babeljs.io/en/setup#installation) to set it up correctly with the build tools you are using. Also be sure to add `preset/react` in your presets since you are using react.

Otherwise, you can use `create-react-app` to get a boilerplate for your app. `create-react-app` comes preconfigured with babel and webpack and you will not have to the extra setup.

Comment: When I clicked the link I didn't see a preset for react.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react. You can add it to your presets list.

Comment: I added it, and I'm getting the error message for some reason.